# How to set a default value to checked for a C1flexgrid checkbox column?

Tags: c#, c1flexgrid

I have WF, and one of the column in C1flexgrid has Boolean data type. 
By default, all of the check boxes are unchecked on the load of that form, but I am wondering how to set values to checked on all rows of that column?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is the solution:

```
for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < grid.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
{
  grid[rowIndex, 1] = 1;
}
```

Number one in this [ ] brackets is column index.